# Check whether two arraylists contains the same elements

Tags: .net, vb.net, arraylist

I have two arraylist; list1 and list2.  It contains objects inside the arraylist.

How can I check whether two arraylists contains the same elements?

I tried with equals, but it seems it always returns false.

Comment: You shouldn't use `ArrayList`. Instead, use the generic `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the somewhat deprecated `System.Collections` you should use the generic counterpart `System.Collections.Generic`. There are various advantages described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You can create a generic method to determine whether two collections are the same or not:

```
Private Function UnanimousCollection(Of T)(ByVal firstList As List(Of T), ByVal secondList As List(Of T)) As Boolean
    Return firstList.SequenceEqual(secondList)
End Function
```

Sample Usage:

```
Dim teachers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Alex", "Maarten"})
Dim students As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Alex", "Maarten"})
Console.WriteLine(UnanimousCollection(teachers, students))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use arraylist you can convert them to IEnumberable and then use linq intersection.

```
static bool IsSame(ArrayList source1, ArrayList source2)
{
    var count = source1.Count;
    // no use comparing if lenghts are different
    var diff = (count != source2.Count);
    if (!diff)
    {
        // change to IEnumberable<object>
        var source1typed = source1.Cast<object>();
        var source2typed = source2.Cast<object>();
        // If intersection is the same count then same objects
        diff = (source1typed.Intersect(source2typed).Count() == count);
    }
    return diff;
}
```